# AttributeError: 'open3d.open3d.geometry.LineSet' object has no attribute 'create_from_point_cloud_correspondences'

Tags: python, open3d

I'm currently using Open3D to draw correspondences among two point clouds. According to the [document](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/python_api/open3d.geometry.LineSet.html#open3d.geometry.LineSet.create_from_point_cloud_correspondences), they have a static function called "create from point cloud correspondences",but when I try to run it, it gave an error saying

> AttributeError: 'open3d.open3d.geometry.LineSet' object has no
>   attribute 'create_from_point_cloud_correspondences'

My code is like this with "source" and "target" being the point clouds and "a" being the correspondence.

```
line_set = o3d.geometry.LineSet()
line_set = line_set.create_from_point_cloud_correspondences(source,target,a)
```